# Htm page to Aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have an htm page.There i have a link Moreinfo.When we click that link it will go to aspx  page.Means here the link Moreinfo [More Info...](http://localhost/akki/akki/b/reg.aspx) when we click that link it has to go reg.aspx.But its not going,,error is shopwing page not found

Means In my project,i have index.htm.From this page when i click Moreinfo link,,it has to go reg.aspx..How i can go..I copied this proj from my collegue

Nothing is working .both index.htm and reg.aspx are in same site 'b'

Comment: Yes...err... the page is not being found!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the path of the link is correct?  The link you have here is showing http://localhost/akki/akki/b/reg.aspx - are you sure there are supposed to be two "akki"s in the path?

Comment: Means In my project,i have index.htm.From this page when i click Moreinfo  link,,it has to go reg.aspx..How i can go..I copied this proj from my collegue

Comment: Nothing is working .both index.htm and reg.aspx are in same site 'b'

Comment: What does the URL look like when you are looking at index.htm?

Answer (score 0):

the error means that the aspx page does not exist at the link you are pointing to. either you have given a wrong link or your aspx page does not exist on the path you intend to.

Comment: Nothing is working .both index.htm and reg.aspx are in same site 'b'